# Angular load JSON into FormArray without flexible Userinput afterwards

Tags: angular

I receive once a JSON from an API when loading the page. I’d like to generate a table with inputs from the JSON array.

`` `[   {itemName: 'Test1', itemNumber: 420},    {itemName: 'Test2', itemNumber: 690} ];` ``

For each element in the array, it generates one more column. This works already.
https://imgur.com/a/LfScOh1

Now I’d like to use common validators on all labels to check for duplicates over all existing labels. As far as I understand, I need for validators Reactive forms and FormArray.

I spend the whole day googling around, but every example is with dynamic forms, if e.g. the user adds with a click one more column.

This is too much for me. At my application, only the JSON defines the number of columns when loading the page.

Is FormArray the right approach to go?

Angular doc:
“However, you don't need to define a key for each control by name, so this is a great option if you don't know the number of child values in advance.”
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms

What means advance here? Advance before loading the page or before writing code?

.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="myDataArr" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="itemName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="margin-bottom: -1.25em">
                  <input matInput autocorrect="off"
                  autocapitalize="off"
                  spellcheck="off"
                  type="text"
                  required value={{element.itemName}} />
              </mat-form-field>
      </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Number Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="itemNumber">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> itemNumber </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.itemNumber}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface aDataArray {
  itemName: string;
  itemNumber: number;
}

const CONST_DATA: aDataArray[] = [
  {itemName: 'Test1', itemNumber: 420},
  {itemName: 'Test2', itemNumber: 690}
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  myDataArr = CONST_DATA;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['itemName', 'itemNumber'];
}
```